# RxJava - groupBy, toMap and flatMap not working well together?

Tags: java, functional-programming, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I would expect this small example to print all numbers which are divisible by 3.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Observable.range(1, 100)
            .groupBy(n -> n % 3)
            .toMap(g -> g.getKey())
            .flatMap(m ->  m.get(0))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

The `println` is not printing anything instead, and I don't get why.

I reduced this example from a more complex one, I understand this can be done in a different way, but I need it this way as there are more groups involved which needs to be manipulated in the `flatMap` at the same time.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not just `filter(n -> n % 3 == 0)`?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Works for me in both RxJava 1 and 2 (you need `flatMapObservable` there). What version are you running on?

Comment: it's an old version unfortunately which I am constraint to, that might be the issue I guess than. I don't have the project in front of me atm but I recall it being 0.14.something. Do you think I should do something different with this version?

Comment: 0.14 is ancient (or 1.0.14?) and both `groupBy` and `flatMap` had several bugs over the years.

Comment: Definitely 0.14, we probably need to spend some time on upgrading to a newer version. Is the upgrade path to v1 or v2 easy? Also I would like to set your comment as accepted answer, but cannot as it's a comment. If you write an answer instead I would be happy to do so. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @akarnokd stated on a comment above, the example works with the latest version of RxJava v1 and v2, but doesn't work on the version we are using (com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-core:jar:0.16.1, which is ancient) probably due to a bug in the library itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method [`filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#filter-io.reactivex.functions.Predicate-) instead of [`groupBy(..)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#groupBy-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) to emit the elements that satisfy a specified predicate.

```
Observable.range(1, 100)
    .filter(n -> n % 3 == 0)
    .toMap(g -> g.getKey())
    .flatMap(m ->  m.get(0))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Java Stream-API works on the same principle:

```
IntStream.range(1, 100).filter(n -> n%3 == 0).forEach(System.out::println);
// prints 3, 6, 9, 12... on the each line
```

Comment: I am sorry, then the question is unclear to me. I've asked you to provide the expected output to make the issue clear.

Comment: it's written on the first line of the question, it should print all numbers divisible by 3. @akarnokd is on the right track in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

The [groupBy](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/groupby.html) operator maps the input source items to `HashMap` where the latest value is stored under the key.

Quoting the documentation:

`If more than one source item maps to the same key, the HashMap will contain the latest of those items.`

So in your case the `toMap` operator transforms the input sequence into the following `HashMap`:

`{0=99, 1=100, 2=98}`

To filter out all numbers indivisible by 3 from the range specified just use `filter` operator as @Nikolas advised.